# mysql join tables in which field from 1st table as multiple value in second table

Tags: php, mysql

This question may be silly but I want to know whether it is possible in mysql.

`  **Course_Table:**

```
|--------------|-
|id | name     |
----|----------|
|1  |HTML5     |
|2  |CSS3      |
|3  |JavaScript|
|4  |PHP       |
|5  |MySQL     |
---------------|
```

**User_Table**

```
--------------
|id |name    |
---------------
|1  |Alice   |   
|2  |Bob     |
|3  |Caroline|
|4  |David   | 
|5  |Emma    |
--------------
```

---

**user_course**

```
---------------------------
|id |  userid      |course|
---------------------------
|1  |   1      | 1    |
|2  |   1      | 2    |
|3  |   1      | 4    |
|4  |   3      | 1    |
|5  |   3      | 5    |
---------------------------`
```

And I want my result to be like this

```
` --------------------------
 | username  |  course     |
  -------------------------|
 |Alice    | HTML,CSS3,php |
 |Caroline | HTML,MYSQL    |
 --------------------------`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join the tables first using `INNER JOIN` since you only want to show users with course.

There is a builtin function in MySQL called [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which concatenates rows.

```
SELECT  a.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) courseList
FROM    user_table a
        INNER JOIN user_course b
            ON a.id = b.userid
        INNER JOIN course_table c
            ON b.course = c.id
GROUP   BY a.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/356228/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Can you help me with the following question?